# How to transform object to array before parsing in Zod

Tags: reactjs, typescript, integration, zod

I do have an external URL endpoint that **returns an array of field object when it is more than 2 and an object when there is only one**, see the snippet below:

Return when the field count is one:

```
{
  "fields": { "fullName": "fieldFullname", "type": "fieldType" }
}
```

Return when the field is more than one:

```
{
  "fields": [
      { "fullName": "fieldFullname", "type": "fieldType" },
      { "fullName": "fieldFullname", "type": "fieldType" }
   ]
}
```

Currently, this is my schema using zod:

```
export const sObjectMetadataSchema = z.object({
  fields: z.array(metadataFieldSchema).optional()
});

export const metadataFieldSchema = z.object({
  fullName: z.string().optional(),
  type: z.string().optional(),
});
```

It is configured that it will only accept an array of objects. When it returns only one field it throws an error:

```
{
  "code": "invalid_type",
  "expected": "array",
  "received": "object",
  "path": [],
  "message": "Expected array, received object"
}
```

My goal is if it returns a single object it will convert it to an array of objects during runtime. Currently trying to implement using `transform` but still not working:

An initial implementation using transform:

```
export const sObjectMetadataSchema = z.object({
fields: z.unknown().transform((rel) => {
    return Array.isArray(rel)
        ? z.array(metadataFieldSchema).optional()
        : 'Convert the rel to Array?';
    }),
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I didn't test that, but seems like should work:

```
const FieldsSchema = z.object({
  fullName: z.string(),
  type: z.string()
});

export const sObjectMetadataSchema = z.object({
fields: z.union([FieldsSchema, FieldsSchema.array()]).transform((rel) => {
    return Array.isArray(rel)
        ? rel
        : [rel];
    }),
});
```

Comment: My god! you save my day @Konrad, It works perfectly. Thanks mate!

Comment: z.union returns a type that does not allow for further validations.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks for the answer @Konrad !

I improved it a little bit in typescript, so it is also typed correctly:

```
const arrayFromString = <T extends ZodTypeAny>(schema: T) => {
  return z.preprocess((obj) => {
    if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
      return obj;
    } else if (typeof obj === "string") {
      return obj.split(",");
    } else {
      return [];
    }
  }, z.array(schema));
};
```

Comment: I'd add this is preferred not only for the TypeScript but because `preprocess` runs before validation occurs. As of `v3.22.2` the [docs for preprocess](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod#preprocess) mention "But sometimes you want to apply some transform to the input before parsing happens. A common use case: type coercion. Zod enables this with the z.preprocess()."